# How can I transfer pictures from a Macbook Pro to an iPad I don't own?

Tags: itunes, ipad, photos.app, data-transfer, file-transfer

My parents would like to have a copy of most of the photos that are stored within iPhoto.

I can't find the files on the hard drive, and don't know the best way to transfer them to an iPad that isn't mine.  (There is no iCloud account in common between the devices)

What is the best way to send iPhoto images to an iPad?

Answer (score 1):

Not perfect for so many images, but the simplest known solution would be the **cross copy** tool. I created this Open Source project to target the ongoing hassle of inter-device file transfer:

1. Download and install the App called cross copy (or open http://www.cross-copy.net if you prefer the web app)
2. Enter the same code word on both devices (the more unique the merrier security)
3. start uploading files --- they will instantly appear on the other side

To be honest, the App should (and could) be extended to make multi file upload possible -- otherwise transfering a whole collection of images is much to cumbersome.